# MS Access linked table to SQL Server update record

Tags: database, ms-access, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 (`Table1`) and I have created an MS Access 2016 database and then created a linked table in MS Access to `Table1` in SQL Server 2012 using a System DSN.

This works fine, I can open the linked Table1 in MS Access 2016 see the columns and update the values. I have then created a Form in MS Access 2016, added the columns from Table1 to the Form and I can see the data fine.

The problem I have is that the option to Add New Record is greyed out and no matter what I try I cannot add a new record to `Table1` using the Form.

If I create a standard (not a linked table) in MS Access 2016 and add the columns to the Form rather than the columns from the Linked Table1 the Add New Record icon is then available.

My question is... Is it possible to use a Form in MS Access 2016, have the data source as a Linked Table to a table in SQL Server 2012 and add new records to it? (And if so, how do I achieve this as I've been at this now for hours and hours and cannot figure it out).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice.  If I open the linked table I can add a new record and it appears in the linked MS Access and Sql Server table just fine.  When I try and add a new entry in the MS Access form the Add New Record is greyed out still.  The Sql Server table has a Primary Key and is correctly configured (I've been a Sql Server developer/DBA for 15 years and have also build numerous MS Access Application over the years, just never using linked tables).

Comment: Do you have `Allow Additions` set to no on the form properties?

Answer (score 1):

You note that you can update values when you click on the linked table and view the rows.

Can you ADD rows when using that linked table? And if you cannot, then open up the table using SQL Management Studio and try adding rows that way?

If you don’t have correct (or any) settings in SQL server that sets up or increments the primary key, then you can’t add rows (automatic in this context).

So make sure  the table has a primary key, make sure you can add rows using SSMS. If you make changes to fix this SQL table, then you have to re-link the table.

I suggest you create a primary key in the SQL table, and make it a identity column with a increment of 1.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible; this is a very common approach.  It sounds like the login you used in the System DSN to connect to SQL Server does not have INSERT permissions on the table.  Are you able to review the permissions to check that?

Answer (score -2):

The auto-insertion/update doesn't work for link-database. You need to write a VBA code behind your interface.

Below solution can give you a basic and simple heads up:

[Inserting into SQL Server using MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104925/inserting-into-sql-server-using-ms-access)

Comment: Incorrect - Access has worked without issue for 20 years using linked tables and inserting new rows. So yes auto insert in a form or editing the linked table in Access works just fine.

Answer (score -2):

Have a similar situation. Linked Sql Server table, Access Form front end. I am able to insert/update/delete via the form. However, I then created a checkbox to implement a filter on the data. When the box is not checked, I can still edit the data. However, as soon as I check the box to activate the filter, I can no longer insert/update/delete. When I uncheck the box, I can again edit the data. So in my case,  the problem is due to the filter, which is implemented via a VBA query involving both an outer join and a union. The query replaces the form's control source when activated, and I believe it is simply too complex for Access to treat it as updatable.